# Convert matrix to a Diagonal Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector and I need to convert it to a diagonal matrix. My vector is as follows

```
>>> mymatrix
    matrix([[36, 66, 96]])
```

Expected output is

```
 36 0  0
 0  66 0
 0  0  96
```

I tried `np.diag(mymatrix)` but it gives only `[[36]]` result. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`diagflat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagflat.html) because your input is a matrix:

```
np.diagflat(mymatrix)
Out: 
matrix([[36,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 66,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 96]])
```